# Make react electron app draggable with transparent frame

Tags: reactjs, sass, electron, draggable

I am trying to implement this in a React Electron app. I've tried using the CSS properties as listed above, but it is not working yet. The other solution with the browser window doesn't quite work either as my application is in React with the App wrapped in a Context.Provider. Here is the code I have:

In app.tsx

```
<ApplicationContext.Provider value={{
    ...this.state,

  }}
>
<div id="app" className={appTheme}>
  <header className="title-bar">
    {/* more code */}
  </header>
</div>
```

And this in App.scss

```
.title-bar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

Anyone know if there is a better strategy for solving this in a React Electron app?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what do you mean by "draggable with transparent frame"?

Comment: When you create the BrowserWindow in the electron file, you can set the frame: false, this will remove the default browser grey window frame that you can typically click and drag the window around with. When it is removed, the window becomes non-draggable. The documentation and other suggestions on SO suggest adding some criteria in css that will allow for the window to be draggable, but it is not working. Once the frame is set to false, the electron window is stuck on the screen it appears on, and you can only resize it, but cannot move it to another screen if you want to. This is not ideal.

Comment: I just tried on my own React/Electron app the `frame: false;` and `-webkit-app-region: drag;` properties and it works fine. However, I don't use `Context.Provider`. 

Answer (score 1):

*llamacorn  -webkit-app-region: drag is known to have problems while the developer tools are open. See this GitHub issue for more information including a workaround. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3647*
 Source: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure why I am getting this behavior, but in case this helps others I'll just post what I did to resolve my issue.

I was running Electron 5, I upgraded to the latest version v7 on the project, and globally on my machine. Additionally, the Electron window would launch with a Chrome dev tools window docked to the right of the app. When I closed that, I was able to drag the window. I was able able to undock the dev tools, and that also allowed the window to be draggable.